# how to fix Invalid gemspec

Tags: rubygems, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04, gemspecs

I found a bug when checking the `vagrant` version in ubuntu terminal
It returns these following error:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/rbnacl-libsodium.gemspec]: stack level too deep
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your vagrant that works. 
Download direct from the vagrant website and don't use the version of ubuntu repository `apt-get install vagrant`.

The ubuntu version is outdated.
Solved from: [github issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9788)

Comment: If this was true in the past, it no longer works, possibly because that gem is discontinued. For me, I had to delete /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/rbnacl-libsodium.gemspec .

Comment: but last year it worked for me. and thanks for this info